# How to prove that $\{x∈R^n|\| \ x-x_0\| \leq \epsilon\}$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

how to prove that $$\{x∈R^n|\| \ x-x_0\| \leq \epsilon\}$$ is closed?
I found that the complement of this is $$\{x∈R^n|\| \ x-x_0\| > \epsilon\}$$ and hence wrote that as there are $\delta > 0$ that makes $N_\delta(x) \subset [x∈R^n|\| \ x-x_0\| > \epsilon]$ and therefore the complement is open set and   $$\{x∈R^n|\| \ x-x_0\| \leq \epsilon\}$$ is closed set. I know that this is not complete proof but I have no idea how to get further on.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a complete proof? Another way to show this is to use that $x\mapsto\|x-x_0\|$ is continuous.

Comment: I fixed up the vanishing curly brackets in your set notation.  The characters `{ }` have a special role in MathJax, so the are not parsed as visible characters unless "escpaped" by prepending the backslash, e.g. `\{ \}`.

Comment: Other than [tag:general-topology], your tags don't seem relevant to the problem.  That one relevant tag is enough, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing missing is to explain why such a $\delta$ exists. Take $y_0\in\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid\|x-x_0\|>\varepsilon\}$ and let $\delta=\|y_0-x_0\|-\varepsilon$. Then, if $\|y-y_0\|<\delta$, we have\begin{align}\|y-x_0\|&=\|y-y_0+y_0-x_0\|\\&\geqslant\|y_0-x_0\|-\|y-y_0\|\\&>\|y_0-x_0\|-\delta\\&=\|y_0-x_0\|-\bigl(\|y_0-x_0\|-\varepsilon\bigr)\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following result: Given an nonempty set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, for $\forall \{x_k\}\subset A$ such that $\lim x_k=x$, if $x\in A$, then $A$ is closed. Let
$$A=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid\|x-x_0\|\le\varepsilon\}.$$
For $\forall \{x_k\}\subset A$ such that $\lim x_k=x$, then
$$ \|x_k-x_0\|\le\varepsilon. $$
Letting $k\to\infty$ gives
$$\|x-x_0\|\le\varepsilon$$
which implies $x\in A$. So $A$ is closed.